# Understanding Java's "final" for translation to C#

Tags: c#, java, final

I am not a Java programmer. I read the documentation on "final", and understand it to mean "a variable's value may be set once and only once."

I am translating some Java to C#. The code does not execute as expected. I tried to figure out why, and found some uses of final that don't make sense.

Code snippet 1:

```
final int[] PRED = { 0, 0, 0 };
...
PRED[1] = 3;
```

Will PRED[1] be 0 or 3?

Code snippet 2:

```
final int[] PRED = new int[this.Nf];
for (int nComponent = 0; nComponent < this.Nf; nComponent++) {
    PRED[nComponent] = 0;
}
...
PRED[1] = 3;
```

Surely PRED[0] will remain as 0?

Comment: Try that out here, select Java, then click sample: http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the `final` keyword semantic when it is applied to arrays in Java.

In both Java examples the arrays will remain unchanged, but their elements may be changed. All your assignments will be executed correctly, and the values stored in the array will get changed. However, if you try

```
final int[] PRED = new int[this.Nf];
// some other code
PRED = new int[123]; // <<== Compile error
```

you are going to see a compile error.

When translating your code to C#, you may need to translate `final` either as `sealed` (when it is applied to a `class`), or as `readonly` (when it is applied to a member). The semantic of `readonly` arrays in C# and `final` arrays in Java are the same: your program cannot reassign the array, but it can freely modify its elements.

Finally, there is a Java-specific case when `final` is used where you wouldn't need it in C# at all: when you need to use a variable inside a method of an anonymous local class in Java, you must make that variable `final`. Since C# does not have anonymous local classes, you would need to translate that piece of code with something else, perhaps with anonymous delegates. Such delegates are not restricted to using readonly variables.

Comment: I believe "sealed" prevents inheritance and has no other function. How would that equate to a use of "final"?

Comment: In Java you can prevent inheritance by declaring your class `final` in the same way that you "seal" a class in C#. That's why I mentioned that the meaning of `final` keyword in java is dependent on the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for in C# is "const":

```
const int SOMETHING = 10;
```

Note that the SIZE should be constant as well.

Also, constants can only be of type int, bool, string, char, etc (basic types only).

So if you want something else, such as an array or a class, you can do:

```
static readonly int[] PRED = new int[this.Nf];
```

Static Readonly means exactly const, logically, except it is defined a little differently backstage, which allows you to play more freely with it. (When you CAN - you SHOULD define constants instead of static readonly's)

The array itself will not change during the run, so you will not be able to do this:

```
PRED = new int[3]; // Error
PRED = null; // Error
PRED = PRED; // Error
```

But you CAN change values INSIDE the PRED array:

```
PRED[0] = 123;
```

If you wish to have a readonly collection, you can use the ReadOnlyCollection object!
If you also want that object to be constant, you can use the static-readonly combination (you can't use constant because it is a class), and you will get:

```
static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<int> PRED = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new[] {1, 2, 5, 6});
```

And then PRED will always be PRED, and will always be of size 4, and will always contain 1, 2, 5, 6.

```
PRED = PRED; // Error (static readonly)
PRED = null; // Error (static readonly)
PRED[1] = 0; // Error (ReadOnlyCollection enforces readonly on the elements)

int i = PRED[1]; // Still works, since you aren't changing the collection.
```

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken, but your answer seems do differ from the others. Specifically, @dasblinkenlight is saying the values can change, which would violate a const or readonly.

Comment: The array itself will not change ever, but it's values within it can change. Just as you can define a static readonly MyClass, yet change it's properties. See edit.

Comment: @YoryeNathan regarding constant, that doesn't work, compile time error. check this: http://ideone.com/G7Ven

Comment: regarding `final int[] PRED = { 0, 0, 0 };` it's equivalent to C# is not `static readonly int[] PRED = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };`. It's just `readonly int[] PRED = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };`. This is another thing `static readonly int[] PRED = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };`

Comment: `final` is instance scoped? I thought it was exactly the same as `const`

Comment: final isn't the same as const... the semantics are quite different. final is more like readonly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ReadOnlyCollection<T>!

Answer (score 2):

final is checked by the compiler, not at runtime. So if the assignment `PRED[1] = 3` was invalid, it would be caught by the compiler and the code wouldn't even compile.

This assignment is valid, because final means: you can't reassign another value to the variable. It doesn't mean: you can't mutate the object referenced by the variable.

The above assignment doesn't modify the value of `PRED`. It modifies the value of `PRED[1]`. If PRED was a list, the equivalent would be `PRED.set(1, 3)`. Which is OK. What would be incorrect would be `PRED = new ArrayList<Integer>()`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a value to be set only once though instead of final in java use readonly in c#, or const, or in some cases sealed should be used, though readonly probably better if you only want to read ;)

Comment: I am only trying to understand how to interpret the Java :)

Comment: you put a c# tag on the question, hence why i thought you wanted a c# answer ;)

Comment: No worries. But yes, I am translating to C#, so I tagged both :)

Comment: well if youre translating to c# youll need to know about the things i mentioned in the post then :P good luck to you!

Comment: True! And fortunately, I knew what you posted :). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated a `final` variable can only be **set** once. But is legal to change its values.

Answer (score 1):

The Java final keyword is used in the Java programming language under different conditions and has different implications. For example:

1. To declare a constant variable,
2. To declare a constant method parameter.

   1. A variable declared as final must have an initialization prior to its usage. This variable cannot be assigned a new value such as (a = b). But if the variable is not of primitive type then its properties can be set using the set methods or any other public fields. This means that the object instance reference cannot be changed but the properties of the object instance can be changed as long as they themselves are not declared final.
   2. To prohibit the parameter being modified in the method where it is being used.